# Loop doesn't terminate upon checking a condition

Tags: ruby

This loop does not terminate after I type x. I'm really new to Ruby, and so far, it is so much different than what I learned before - quite interesting,

```
total = 0
i = 0

while ((number = gets) != "x")
    total += number.to_i
    i += 1
end

puts  "\nAverage: " + (total / i).to_s
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `gets` gives you the newline as well. You need to [`chomp`](http://www-users.math.umd.edu/~dcarrera/ruby/0.3/chp_02/user_input.html) it.

Try:

```
while ((number = gets.chomp) != "x")
```

and you'll see it starts working:

```
pax> ruby testprog.rb
1
5
33
x

Average: 13
```